# SQLAlchemy won't find the column in my table even after updating DB?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

When I run my code, I receive this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: user.about
[SQL: SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.username AS user_username, user.email AS user_email, user.image_file AS user_image_file, user.password AS user_password, user.root AS user_root, user.about AS user_about
FROM user
WHERE user.id = ?]
[parameters: (6,)]
```

This table does exist and has a default value set, how do I stop this from happening?

Edit: My models.py:
This is the models python file which i have, some irrelevant bits are cut out.

```
from website import db, login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin
from itsdangerous import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer as Serializer
from flask import current_app

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

followers = db.Table('followers',
    db.Column('follower_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('followed_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
)

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
    root = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    about = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=True, default="Welcome to my page!")
```

Edit 2: If I try `User.__table__.columns.keys()` Then that just prints out:
`['id', 'username', 'email', 'image_file', 'password', 'root', 'about']` like it should but still user.about is not recognised?

Comment: Maybe your user.about column doesn´t exist in your table. can you upload your table structure?

Comment: you would get error "table user does not exist" if it didn't so as @nacho says it must be the column not being part of the table

Comment: @nacho I added the file

Comment: did you change any column names before the error? is dropping and recreating the tables an option?

Comment: @AndrewAllen Nope i didn't change any names and unfortunately dropping tables would be quite hard for me, I could try that if it was a last saviour but i'd like to try something else instead

Comment: what does `User.__table__.columns.keys()` give you?

Comment: it gives me this: `['id', 'username', 'email', 'image_file', 'password', 'root', 'about']`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from a guy on reddit (russon77), basically just download SQLBrowser and edit and make columns from there which are the same and it works, not much need for migration or anything of that stuff!